# Why is the file storing binary characters? getw() and putw() were asked to be used in the question

Tags: c, text-files, binaryfiles, file-handling

I've used a ".txt" extension while reading and writing the file, also the file mode is corresponding to that of "text" type of file. The program runs fine, but instead of storing an ASCII character in the file, it is storing binary characters. I need some assistance here. Thank you. [image]

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int n2, n1;
    printf("ENTER A NUMBER: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    fp = fopen("hello.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%d", n1);
    //fclose(fp);
    //rewind(fp);
    fp = fopen("hello.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
    //n2 = getw(fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", n1);
    printf("%d", n1);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Why is the `fclose` in the middle commented out?

Comment: I think you'd want `fscanf(fp, "%d", &n1);` note the `&`.

Comment: It was working the same before and after, so i had commented it out temporarily.

Comment: The question assigned to me mandated the use of getw() and putw(), otherwise it was all fine.

Comment: `printf("ERRROR")` does not provide a useful error message.  Use: `const char *path="hello.txt"; fp = fopen(path, "r"); if (fp == NULL){ perror(path); exit(1); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to close and reopen the file you don't need `rewind`. Or you can open the file to read and write, and then you can use `rewind`. Both work, here is a sample of the latter:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int n2, n1;
    printf("ENTER A NUMBER: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n1) == 1) // checking if the input was correctly parsed
    {
        fp = fopen("hello.txt", "w+"); // open to read and write
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR");
            exit(1);
        }
        putw(n1, fp); // write to the file

        rewind(fp); // go back to the beginning of the file

        n2 = getw(fp);    // get the data

        printf("%d", n2);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Bad input");
    }
}
```

[**Live sample**](https://godbolt.org/z/seb171)

There is still the matter of possible integer overflow when reading from `stdin`, if there is no requirement to guard against that, make sure to at least document the vulnerability, otherwise the advice is to use `fgets` to read input and `strtol` to convert the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should send address of a variable in `fscanf`, like this:

```
fscanf(fp,"%d",&n1);
```

Comment: Actually i was supposed to use getw() here (question mandated that). I'd used fscanf() it was all fine.